# How come my python import doesn't work?

Tags: python

This works:

```
from story.apps.document import core
print core.submit()
```

This doesn't work:

```
from story import apps
print apps.document.core.submit()
```

"story" is a directory. Inside it, there is "apps" directory. Inside it, there is "document" directory.  "core.py" is a file.

There is a `__init__.py` in every directory.

Answer (score 8):

The `__init__.py` file tells python to interpret the directory as a package, but it does not necessarily tell python to import sub-packages or other files from the directory (although it may, if you add the appropriate `import` statements).

With large package hierarchies, it is often preferable to require sub-packages to be imported explicitly.

Answer (score 7):

When you do `story.apps.document import core`, you're telling the Python interpreter to match a module of the description `story.apps.document`, import it, then load the variable `core` from its namespace into your current one.

Because `core` is a file module it has in its namespace variables defined within that file e.g., `submit`.

---

When you do `from story import apps`, you're telling the Python interpreter to match a module of the description `story`, import it, then load the variable `apps` from its namespace into your current one.

Because `apps` is a directory module it has within its namespace variables defined in its `__init__.py` and other modules in that directory. So `apps` knows about the `document` but it doesn't know anything about `document`'s submodule `core`.

---

**FYI:** The reason this sometimes confuses people is because of stuff like this...

Works just fine:

```
# File1
import story.apps.document
story.apps.document.core()
```

Doesn't work:

```
# File2
import story
story.apps.document.core() # <-- Looks like the same function call, but is an Error
```

For `file1`, The import works because the the `import` operation tries to intelligently find things on the filesystem. The function call works because the module `document` was imported, and it is merely named `story.apps.document`.

For `file2`, the function call doesn't work because there's nothing intelligent about the dot operator, it merely attempts to access attributes on the Python object--it doesn't know anything about filesystems or modules.

Comment: What can be even more confusing to people is that if `file1` is imported first, then `file2` will work (since `file1` already did the necessary heavy lifting to get everything imported correctly)

Answer (score 1):

when you do from story import apps, you don't include all the subpackages inside apps, for that, you do something like,

from story.apps.document import *

Answer (score 1):

This only works if `story/__init__.py` imports `apps`.

Answer (score 0):

IN the second example you are only importing the package. Python does not automatically import subpackages or modules. You have to explicitly do it, as in the first example. Do a `dir(apps)` and you'll see it is just an empty package.